# How to add shortcuts to Menu (not MenuItem) in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to do menu like this (with shortcuts):

[image]

So, I did:

```
Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
fileMenu.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.F, KeyCombination.ALT_DOWN));
```

But it doesn't work. When I press ALT+F nothing happens. Besides, I don't know how to make key letters underlined. Can anyone say how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a ["mnemonic"](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/Mnemonic.html), not an accelerator. Simply put an underscore (`_`) in front of the letter you want to use and ensure the [`mnemonicParsing`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html#mnemonicParsingProperty) property is set to `true`, which it is by default.

For example, the following:

```java
Menu fileMenu = new Menu("_File");
```

Will let you use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to display the menu.

Note this works with `MenuItem` as well (`Menu` extends `MenuItem`). Adding a mnemonic to a `MenuItem` provides another way for your user to fire the item's action (in addition to clicking it, using an accelerator, etc.).

---

**Warning:** Mnemonics are not supported on all platforms (e.g., Macs). Consequently, you may want to define the accelerator as well.

Comment: Note that mnemonics will only apply on platforms that use mnemonics (e.g. windows).  Other platforms (e.g. Macs), use accelerators rather than mnemonics, so you may wish to define those as well.

Comment: @jewelsea I assume it just won't work on Macs then? Or does JavaFX behave as if `mnemonicParsing` is set to `false` and render the text with the underscore in front of the letter?

Comment: it just doesn't work on Macs, mnemonics do nothing, they only rely on accelerators (which most Mac apps use extensively). Official documentation by [Apple references mnemonics as a deprecated feature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscell/1560878-mnemonic), so I guess it was originally supported some time in the distant past.